# How can i make a blank square coming from out of the screen on a click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, leaflet

I have a small problem when developing an interactive map.
I'm trying to make a square of information appear on the map by clicking on one of the buttons on the left.
I am wondering what is the best solution to achieve this.
I think I need to create a div with my information square with a display:none , which is displayed when clicking on the button with a display: block.
The problem is that with this way of doing it, no animation occurs.

For reference, I would like an animation in this style https://infrastructure.aws/ , when you click on region, you see the square coming out of the screen with the information.

The link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/paul-k/pen/BaLXKNW
The button where i want to add the event listener is

`<button id="Regions">Regions</button>`

Do you know in which way i can reproduce something like this?

Thank you very much,
Have a nice day

Comment: make the div **absolute** by default, with the `rigth: -100%` rule. And on click assign the rule `right: 0`. In this case, the animation will work.

Answer (score 0):

Had done something like this with js.
Here is my code

```
document.getElementById('open_button').addEventListener('click',
    function()
    {
        document.querySelector('.square').style.visibility = "visible";
        document.querySelector('.square').style.opacity = "1";
    });

document.getElementById('close_button').addEventListener('click',
    function()
    {
        document.querySelector('.square').style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector('.square').style.opacity = "0";
    });
```

There are button for opening square with class 'open_button' and button for closing square with class 'close_button'. And the element (square, mostly modal) you want to open or close with class 'square'.

Using visibility will solve your problem with animation (for example I used opacity for smooth transition).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i will try this now :)